# How do I remove Bluetooth devices from my Ubuntu phone

Tags: ubuntu-touch, bluetooth

I have tried to pair my phone with the infotainment system in my van and it failed. I can see the system in the BT list, but the option to 'remove device' is greyed out. I can also see the infotainment system of a car I must have parked next to at some stage. The option to remove that is also greyed out.

How do I remove them from the list?

Is there am app or do I need to edit a config file, if so where is it and what needs to be done?

I have am Aquaris E5 running Ubuntu 15.04 OTA 12.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem and solved it by using terminal commands.

Start `bluetoothctl`
Then type `remove xx:xx:xx:xx` (replacing the `xx` stuff with the appropriate device address)

Answer (score 1):

For the 'Forget this device' to be enabled you need to have your Bluetooth turned on, on your phone. If touch turn it on and then click on the item yoy want to remove in toyr Bluetooth list, you should be able to click on Forget this device as the button will now be active.

Comment: Bluetooth is enabled.... when it isn't you can't see any devices. The 'forget this device' option is greyed. I'm guessing that the failed pairing has messed up a config file somewhere.

Comment: I see, when my Bluetooth is not enabled I can still see the devices that are paired, buy not the ones I can connedt too.

Comment: Does anyone know where the config files for bluetooth are kept in Ubuntu Touch?